# Android Studio 1.0 Annotation Processors not choose

Tags: android-studio, butterknife

I would like to use the ButterKnife (Annotation Processor) in the Android Studio.

However, you can not select Compiler (Annotation Processors).

Where other compilers?

Help, plz